# Install JPEG2000 driver in R, rgdal

Tags: r, rgdal

Major Edit: with the upcoming deprecation of `rgdal` and GDAL deprecating functionality with JPEG2000 this is no longer necessary. Further this work can be done with `rNOMADS`.

Good Afternoon;

I am currently working with `.grib` and `.grib2` file formats as found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170823143854/http://dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/). I would like to analyse this data within R and through using the **rgdal** package I "should" be able to. When I run:

```
readGDAL("test.grib2")
```

I get the following error:

```
dec_jpeg2000: Unable to open JPEG2000 image within GRIB file.
Is the JPEG2000 driver available?test.grib2 has GDAL driver GRIB 
and has 751 rows and 1500 columns
Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : 
  Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: 539.88 -90.12  90.12
```

This leads me to believe the JPEG200 driver is my issue, it does not appear within `gdalDrivers()` and I am curious if there is a way to manually install this driver.

Noted on [the GDAL site](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg2000.html) the JPEG2000 driver depends on `libjasper`, and has downloads to source driver files. How do I incorporate those drivers into my rgdal package for use?

Cheers

Comment: Which OS? See the readme docs in rgdal. For Ubuntu or Centos see this as a start.  http://scigeo.org/articles/howto-install-latest-geospatial-software-on-linux.html  Check out rgdal2 on github as an alternative, you can switch between GDAL installs, but it's very different.

Comment: Sorry about that, I realized I hadn't included my OS. I am on Windows 7 64-bit unfortunately. I have utilized cygwin to "install" wgrib2 however I also understand that is not a true installation, within that install jpeg2000 was installed but again, not a true installation. Under the possibility to run this within a linux system its relatively simple from what I can tell. Windows complicates this issue.

Thank you for the info!

Comment: There is build on CRAN using cross compilation but this is not documented for ressons that I cannot fathom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be dealt with using `rNOMADS` and [these instructions](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-rnomads-with-grib-file-support-on-windows/) to install wgrib2. Together this allows for the use of GRIB files.